# How to get only duplicate values out of all keys of an associative array

Tags: php, associative-array, duplicates

i want to extract only duplicates out of all keys of an associative array.. 
The array structure is:

```
Array
(
    [bank_users] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 28
    )

    [bank_link] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 28
        [4] => 28
        [5] => 28
        [6] => 28
        [7] => 28
        [8] => 73
        [9] => 73
        [10] => 73
    )

    [banks] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 28
    )
)
```

Now out of this array, i want a function that should check in each of the key and give me the duplicates.. Like as per the above example **8** and **28** should come out as a result as these values are available in all three keys.. **bank_users, bank_link, banks**.
Pls help...

Answer (score 1):

You need [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) to get the common elements in each array and [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) to reduce them to just one each.

Try

```
$result = array_unique(
  array_intersect($arr['bank_users'], $arr['bank_link'], $arr['banks'])
);
```

Comment: Try with `banks` instead of `bank`.

Comment: yes.. i checked it with proper keys only.. but im sorry.. its nt working fr me.

Comment: I am sorry, it worked.. i did a mistake in keys only.. But my question is that these keys are not fixed, how will i b able to pass them in array_intersect.

Comment: In that case use something like `call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $arr)`

Answer (score -1):

[`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) — Removes duplicate values from an array